# Docker-compose - порт недоступен в контейнере

Tags: docker, docker-compose

У меня есть docker-compose.yml файл:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: customer-support
    build: docker
    env_file: .env.local
    volumes:
      - .:/home/project/app
      - ./docker/supervisord.conf:/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
      - ./docker/supervisord-programs.conf:/etc/supervisor/conf.d/app.conf
    depends_on:
      - composer
    links:
      - rabbitmq
    command: ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
    networks:
      - nt
  composer:
    image: composer
  rabbitmq:
    container_name: rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    networks:
      - nt

networks:
  nt:
    driver: bridge
```

Однако в при запуске кода из контейнера я получаю ошибке "Error Connecting to server(99): Cannot assign requested address", хотя из вне порты доступны

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.0

RUN apt update && apt install -y supervisor

WORKDIR /home/project/app
```

supervisord.conf

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock
chmod=0700

[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory=supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

Comment: `Cannot assign requested address` обычно означает, что приложение пробует открыть сокет используя адрес, который не назначен ни одному сетевому интерфейсу, т.е. грубо говоря используя чужой IP (например, типичная ошибка - использовать IP не из докер контейнера, а с хоста). Покажите, что у вас в секции `inet_http_server` в `supervisord.conf` (кажется это именно supervisord ругается, смотрите полный стектрейс, чтоб понять кто ругается и какую конфигурацию нужно проверять), ну и `Dockerfile` для `app` неплохо бы увидеть.

Comment: Проблема не в супервизоре а в том что не подключается к нужным портам. В супервизоре запускаются консюмеры для rabbitmq, к rabbitmq он не может подключиться

Comment: Как я понимаю через networks создается сеть со своим ip, но как мне его получить?

Comment: Вручную доставать ip не нужно. Контейнеры из одной докер сети (а rabbitmq и app у вас в одной сети - nt) добавляются в hosts (или dns) друг друга под именами сервисов из docker-compose файла. Т.е. из контейнера app доступ к контейнеру с rabbit нужно делать по имени rabbitmq. У вас какой адрес rabbitmq в конфигурации app прописан? Покажите полный стектрейс ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась добавлением subnet и gateway ip в docker-compose

```
networks:
  nt:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
        com.docker.network.enable_ipv6: "false"
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.2.0/24
          gateway: 192.168.2.1
```